# How do I get out of a node group?

Tags: interface, node-editor

I did something I can't get out of! I selected nodes and thinking I'd group them I did a Cntrl + G. Not liking (or understanding) the result, I deleted the nodes. And I'm still left with a green cover that does not allow me to select nodes. :(

[image]

Comment: To enter and exit a node group press **Tab**

Comment: this is the most problematic bottle of Jack Daniels ive seen since new-years

Comment: @Marc Please pay more attention to the tags you use. Twice I've noticed you put the modeling tag on a question about materials. The modeling tag is for actual modeling of surfaces and things similar to that. It's important that we tag things correctly because it effects how things appear when searching. We don't want a bunch of materials questions to pop up when someone searches for modeling. Please keep an eye on that in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enter and exit a node group press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

(Think of it like entering/exiting ***Edit Mode*** for node groups)

Form the [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/node_groups.html?highlight=node%20groups):

> With a group node selected, Tab expands the node to a window frame, and the individual nodes within it are shown. You can move them around, play with their individual controls, re-thread them internally, etc. just like you can if they were a normal part of your editor window. You will not be able, though, to thread them to a node outside the group; you have to use the external sockets on the side of the group node. To add or remove nodes from the group, you need to ungroup them.

Comment: Also Ctrl-Tab will exit a stack of nested node groups.

Answer (score 0):

Short cut to get "Un Group" Press "ALT" + "G"

Or,

[image]

Comment: Tried both! Neither work.

Comment: Try what Cegaton suggested above. Press "Tab" go get out of the Group.

Comment: Sorry. didn't see that comment. That worked. TY.